# Images and styles of website are not displayed in phone browser

Tags: android, html, css, image

I just moved my wordpress website on testing host to check how the website is actually displayed in actual phone browser and it turns out that neither styles nor images are being displayed (as shown in the right side of the image).

Website on desktop browsers works normal and it chrome dev tools if setted on Nexus 5 is displaying okey (as showed in the left side of the image).

[image: Image showing the simulation of phone layout in chrome dev tools and also showing the website being displayed inside the mobile browser]

Answer (score 1):

There is actualy a plugin to take care of this for you. After you have moved the local files to your actual host, run [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/), by searching for the root of your local website and change it to the actual root of your website.

Something like this:

Local: http://localhost/my-wordpress-website/

Live: http://www.my-website.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="logo center-block" src="http://localhost/work/zarakunst/zaratheartist/wp-content/themes/starkers-master/img/zarakunst.png" alt="ZaraKunst logo">
```

You need to replace http://localhost in wp-admin/options-general.php